# How to add at specific Cell of Datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

By the way I'm using `Datagridview` and I stacked at the part of adding/passing to an specific cell:
                  On my Column 0:`col_a`,
                  Column 1:`col_b`,
          Column 2:`col_c`,
          Column 3:`col_d`.

This is my code:

```
     '//pass this to  column b
     Dim fcol As String = txtorder.Text
     '//pass this to  column c
     Dim scol As String = txtQuant.Text

     Dim row As String ()= New String (){fcol,scol}
     DatagridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: The code is Visual Basic ( is it still used....???). Why did you tagged  [tag:c] and [tag:c#]?

Comment: it is because some logic of c# and vb.net are the same. when it comes on datagridview.

Comment: C is not really related to C# — or only extremely remotely related.  It is not appropriate to tag it with C without a lot of careful explanation of why.

Comment: Ah ok sorry for my mistake Sir. by the way Sir can anyone who can help me? At the part of `Cells` and `Rows` of DataGridview?

Answer (score 0):

By the way this is the answer: that i got on internet, It is also for the beginners like me, hope it helps :

```
Dim fcol As String = txtOrder.Text
Dim scol As String = txtQuant.Text

Dim newcol As Integer = Datagridview1.Rows.Add()
Datagridview1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(2).Value = New string() {fcol}
Datagridview1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(3).Value = New string() {scol}
```